How to approach 3rd order nonlinear ODE's
I've been playing around with some equations. I've stumbled across this thing.
$$y'' - y''' + e^y = 0$$
Is it possible to solve this? What approach would I need to take? I haven't worked much with 3rd order ODE's and information appears to be a bit sparse. Chance I could get some tips on how to proceed?

I don't know if this helps but if $z=y'$ then $$y''=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(y'\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y'\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}$$and$$y'''=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(y'\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}\right)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y}\left(y'\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y'\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y'}{\mathrm{d}y}\right)^2+\left(y'\right)^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y'}{\mathrm{d}y^2}$$

If we write $u(x) = \exp y(x)$, the o.d.e. takes the form $P(u''', u'', u', u) = 0$ for some polynomial $P$ of total degree $4$, but I'd be surprised if there were anything like a general solution of it in terms of standard functions.

If we use Sai's substitution the diff eq. becomes
$$z[z'(y)-z'(y)^2-zz''(y)]=-e^{-y}$$
The homogeneous equation is
$$z'(y)-z'(y)^2-zz''(y)=0$$
If we do yet again the same substitution $w=z'$, solving and reversing the substitution, we'd get the homogeneous solution would be
$$1-k_1z+e^{k_1z}=k_2e^{k_1y}$$
One could maybe think about variation of parameters ($k_2=k_2(y)$) to try and solve the original ODE. Once you've got a full solution, you'd reverse the substitution $z=y'$ and solve for $y=y(x)$. I don't think it'll be any easy though.

So by setting $z = y'$, we're making $y$ the new variable. Then we're solving the homogeneous part of that by making another substitution for $w = z'$ in which $z$ is the new variable. This yields $w$ in terms of $z$ which when this is solved, gives the answer $1 - k_1 z + e^{k_1 z} = k_2 e^{k_1 y}$. And the suggestion is to try to solve the original ode using variation of parameters and then reverse the the substitution to get $z$ in terms of $y$ and then solve for $y$. If I understand that all right, I'll give it a shot, thanks for the help all!
